Dictionary is having duplicate keys
Can a Dictionary have duplicate keys? Or is there something else, I am missing?

Here is the code
Dictionary initialization is at class level.
StoredPoints.Keys
Count = 4
[0]: "SN6J1701_B"
[1]: "SN8H1360"
[2]: "SN6P2158"
[3]: "SN6J1701_B"

We receive messages from Kafaka

await _kafkaService.ConsumeMessageWithWait<string, string>(conf, _hostingServiceOption.Topics, source.Token, async (kafkaMessage) =>
{
    try
    {
        if (!ConnectionService.IsCalculationServiceConnected())
        {
            // cancel if no service in listening
            cts.Cancel();
            return;
        }
        NumberOfPointsReceived++;
        Stopwatch.Restart();
        var status = await _dataSenderService.SendMessage(kafkaMessage.Topic, kafkaMessage.Message.Key, kafkaMessage.Message.Value, kafkaMessage.Message.Timestamp);
        Stopwatch.Stop();
        TimeElapsedForProcessing += Stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        _logger.Fatal("{Exception}", ex);
    }
}, true, true);


public class DataSenderService
{
    public record KafkaMessage(string topic, string key, string message, Confluent.Kafka.Timestamp timestamp);
    public static Dictionary<string, List<KafkaMessage>> StoredPoints = new Dictionary<string, List<KafkaMessage>>();

    public async Task<MessageStatus> SendMessage(string topic, string key, string message, Confluent.Kafka.Timestamp timestamp)
    {
        if (!StoredPoints.ContainsKey(key))
         {
            StoredPoints.Add(key, new List<KafkaMessage>());
         }
        StoredPoints[key].Add(kafkaMessage);
        return MessageStatus.Sent;
    }
}

I have compared the keys, both are same. Immediate window shows that and keys are also visible in screenshot


A standard .NET Dictionary does not support multiple entries with the same key. Please post a [mre].

Please include the declaration of StoredPoints and the definition of the type used as key

But what is wrong with your code? You check if StoredPoints has a key, and if it doesnt, you add this key to the dictionary, and then you update value of this key. Its still only one key being in that dict.

string is a reference type and My guess is that its most likely that the references to both values are not the same.  .NET strings are immutable and the runtime caches string values so you avoid new allocations but there are ways to force a new reference. It could also be a bug with the debug view, you might want to check that code out.

The error could be because you have only one key-value pair in your Dictionary, If this is the case the First and Last are going to be same

@Bartosz There are 4 keys in the dictionary where one is duplicate, please see the screenshot, I have pined the dictionary items.

@wohlstad I am not sure I will be able to reproduce it, normally dictionary doesn't behave like this. This was strange to me that's why I am here, if someone knows something.

@MalikRizwan Either this key has some special characters inside that we dont see, or its not an standard dictionary. as wohlstad told you, there is no way of having the same key within a dictionary.

There is one extra pixel in the first key between _ and B, I assume that is an invisible character.

@shingo then what string comparison is doing? please see the screenshot, it returns true that strings are same.

Try to add StringComparison.Ordinal

@MalikRizwan Can give me us the data Mainly the String of both keys that are equal.

@MalikRizwan images can't be copied, compiled and tested. Dictionaries don't allow duplicates, that's not a matter of debate and trivial to prove. You'll have to post code that actually reproduces the problem, as text, so we can take it and test it. A runnable dotnetfiddle would also help

@shingo with StringComparison.Ordinal result is same both strings are same

@MalikRizwan you haven't shown any duplicate keys yet.

I have prepared the screenshot to show that actual running state, i have updated the question and added the keys. @PanagiotisKanavos

@MalikRizwan its not a C# code you posted. Special characters might get removed from Console/Output windows. Please post C# code that initializates your Dictionary.

@PanagiotisKanavos I know that dictionary doesn't allow duplicates, it was strange to me and that's why I am here. Is there some loophole.

Is the method running concurrently?

Print the value of Convert.ToHexString(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(key)) for all keys

@canton7 BitConverter.ToHexString(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(StoredPoints.Keys.First()))
error CS0117: 'BitConverter' does not contain a definition for 'ToHexString'

@MalikRizwan Edited about 10 secs after first posting, see above

@MalikRizwan it's not a loopwhole. What you claim isn't reproducible. Adding those specific keys throws an exception as this fiddle shows. That means the real keys aren't what you assumed or posted here

@PanagiotisKanavos code is running, i havn't stoped if someone want to see the state. I am not sure if this error will be produced again. You can see the dictionary having duplicate keys. Adding duplicate keys in dictionary throws exception, yes you are right, but this is normal behavior. Then what happened here? If a code works fine is some scenarios doesn't  guarantee it will work until doomsday .

@MalikRizwan My suggestion will clearly show whether the keys are actually identical. Please run it.

@MalikRizwan doesn't guarantee it will work until doomsday which means your image proves nothing at all, by your own argument. You haven't posted anything that proves your claim yet. Post actual, runnable code. Extraordinary claims require extraordinary proof and we have none at all

@PanagiotisKanavos Any one can see by his own eyes. But reproduction is not guaranteed.

@canton7 Convert.ToHexString(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(StoredPoints.Keys.ToArray()[0]))
"534E364A313730315F42"
Convert.ToHexString(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(StoredPoints.Keys.ToArray()[3]))
"534E364A313730315F42"

@MalikRizwan yes, it's guaranteed. We don't see anything that proves your claims. How hard is it to just copy those values in a 5 line program and post it here? Did you even check the fiddle I linked to? That's what you need to post

Huh. I'm with @shingo then -- from what I know of Dictionary's internal structure, it's possible to end up with this if you're writing to it from multiple threads at the same time

@PanagiotisKanavos If some car is broken one day at a specific speed, you guarantee on same speed it will be broken again? We know one solution in computer which is very common. Stop it and start again it will work. And 70% this solution works. If i will stop it and start it again it will work fine it is working fine since 10 years for me. But now faced this issue.

I am not here to prove something, I just need explanation so i can avoid this situation. If someone can help. If you don't know anything there is no need to just an argument.

@MalikRizwan just update your question with your code? Otherwise ill vote for this question to be closed as you're wasting everyone's time.

If you don't post code that reproduces the problem it's impossible for people to help. Either the keys are different, or you're incorrectly using multiple threads. Dictionary<> isn't thread-safe. Either use lock to guard access to the dictionary or use a ConcurrentDictionary

@KieranDevlin there nothing special in my code, i am uploading shortly but just this code is updating the dictionary. I know how dictionary should behave and i am working since 10 years and i seen this today. so maybe we need 10 years more to reproduce this again. But i can show a running project it is still stoped in debugging.

Guys, I don't know whether you're being deliberately obstinate, but you're not helping. It's fairly clear that this is a problem which happened once, and is not reproducible. For example, it's related to a race condition, memory corruption, or something else weird. It's clear that an MCVE is not possible -- stop asking for one. This doesn't invalidate the question.

@MalikRizwan The method which adds items to the dictionary: could that be called from multiple threads at the same time?

@KieranDevlin I have uploaded the code, good luck for reproduction. I know this will not happen very soon. But my question is still valid and can show to anyone if someone is interested. I will not stop the VS debugging until i got the answer.

@MalikRizwan Any chance you could answer my question, please. Looking at your code I suspect the answer is "yes"

@canton7 Nope, only one thread. It should not also add the duplicates in any case.

@MalikRizwan Can you post the source for ConsumeMessageWithWait?

@MalikRizwan Also, is there any code which deletes entries from that dictionary? Could that be called at the same time as the code which adds entries to it?

It's an asynchronous call that modifies a singleton, thread-unsafe dictionary without locking. Have you tried using ConcurrentDictionary instead? Or adding lock around SendMessage? BTW the entire check+set code doesn't help. It's no different than just dict[key]=value;. If you want to add only if something doesn't exist, you can use TryAdd. Adding an empty list that gets replaced immediately just leaks objects

@PanagiotisKanavos Re-read it. It's sorting out adding a list as the value, then adding to that list

Yes - something that increases the chances of unintended consequences and begs for TryAdd. Better yet, ConcurrentDictionary<string,ConcurrentQueue<KafkaMessage>>

Also the fact that DataSenderService is a normal class but StoredPoints is static could mean that multiple client/services may be using different DataSenderService instances, all of which try to modify the same dictionary. Even if only one thread is using an instance at a time, the dictionary is still used by multiple threads

@PanagiotisKanavos No other reference for this class. I have shared the only code which is calling this. Again in any case dictionary should not have duplicates.

You're using async methods with a global unsafe collection that's used from potentially multiple clients. It can have duplicates due to race conditions. That's not a rare occurrence either. Sometimes the collection itself detects this and throws an exception. At other times, the two different threads can create new hash buckets for the same key because none of them found a suitable bucket when they first checked if one was needed

@PanagiotisKanavos If i correctly understand you, Dictionary can have duplicate keys?

No, I said it's not thread-safe. That's well known since the first version of .NET, well documented, with a warning in the `Thread Safety* section of the class docs. If you modify it from different threads you'll breakit. There's no guarantee what will happen - just like any other race condition. Just as incrementing a balance by 10 isn't supposed to leave it unchanged or increment it by 20 unless there's a race condition

StoredPoints is public too, so it's possible some other part of the code is trying to modify the dictionary.

This can happen for two reasons. Either the keys are not the same, or multiple threads are modifying the dictionary, and by chance this hadn't resulted in an exception until now. Dictionaries are thread-safe for reading but not for modification. ContainsKey will work, but .Add may well end up mangling the internal hash buckets used by Dictionary.
The StoredPoints is a static (global) property that's accessed by all instances of the normal DataSenderService class. Even if every _kafkaService gets its own DataSenderService, in the end all try to modify the same global dictionary. This could result in race conditions or mixing up the data from unrelated services.
If every DataSenderServices is guaranteed to be only used by a single thread at a time, just making StoredPoints a normal field would solve the problem.
To really make StoredPoints thread safe though, it should be replaced by a ConcurrentDictionary<string,ConcurrentQueue<KafkaMessage>> :
static ConcurrentDictionary<string,ConcurrentQueue<KafkaMessage>> StoredPoints =new();

public async Task<MessageStatus> SendMessage(string topic, string key, string message, Confluent.Kafka.Timestamp timestamp)
{
    var queue=StoredPoints.GetOrAdd(key,
        _=>new ConcurrentQueue<KafkaMessage>());
    queue.Enqueue(kafkaMessage);
    return MessageStatus.Sent;
}

ConcurrentDictionary and ConcurrentQueue are thread-safe using minimal, or even no locking. There's no concurrent equivalent for List<T>.
Using locking
To keep using Dictionary, some form of synchronization must be used to ensure that changes at least don't conflict with each other. As StoredPoints is public, there's no way to prevent the rest of the application from making modifications unless the field is changed to eg a read-only property :
public class DataSenderService
{
    ...
    static object _lock=new object();
    static Dictionary<string, List<KafkaMessage>> _storedPoints 
        = new Dictionary<string, List<KafkaMessage>>();

    // Expose a read-only dictionary to other types
    public static IReadOnlyDictionary<string,List<KafkaMessage>> 
        => _storedPoints;


    public async Task<MessageStatus> SendMessage(string topic, string key, string message, Confluent.Kafka.Timestamp timestamp)
    {
        lock(_lock)
        {
            if (!_storedPoints.ContainsKey(key))
            {
               _storedPoints.Add(key, new List<KafkaMessage>());
            }
            _storedPoints[key].Add(kafkaMessage);
            return MessageStatus.Sent;
        }
    }
}


I can understand the race condition could happen but, i am stuck with dictionary could have duplicates in any case?

Race condition means you have no way of knowing what the dictionary will end up with in the end. The code you posted is susceptible to race conditions, no matter how it seems there's only one thread. If you listen to two Kafka queues, you have multithreaded access to the singleton StoredPoints. If you use async/await in platform without a synchronization context, continuations may well run in a different threadpool thread.

If you read the source of Dictionary, you can see that it has a list of _buckets, which are the hash buckets, and a separate store for the entries called _entries. The buckets each reference an entry (and the entries can be wired into linked lists, which is how you handle multiple items with the same hash), but when you call .Keys / .Values that walks _entries directly....

... If you corrupt the internal state of the dictionary (e.g. with thread-unsafe access), then you might end up with two entries in _entries which have the same key and hash. Only one of them will be referenced from _buckets, but they'll both show up in .Keys / .Values. It's also pretty common to end up with exceptions if you access a dictionary in a thread-unsafe way

@canton7 it's worth noting that at least before .NET Framework 2, there were no exceptions because there were no checks to detect corruption. I don't remember when the checks were added. It could be as late as .NET Framework 4. It was always know that Dictionary is unsafe, but the introduction of Task and later async/await increased the chance of misuse a lot

@PanagiotisKanavos It's pretty easy to get a genuine exception, not one of the concurrent-modification checks. E.g. because there's a race resizing the _entries or _buckets arrays

@PanagiotisKanavos I think you haven't read my question clearly, i have 4 items in the dictionary and 1st and last are same. how a race condition could happen? and in race condition i got two more entries? Between the same entries i have two more entries

@MalikRizwan we've read your question and understood it (canton7, me, everyone else in the discussion). We actually had to handle such things in the past 20+ years, and we already answered. First, that's a different question completely. Second, a race condition can break even a simple addition, never mind a complex operation like modifying the internal structure of a Dictionary, or even a List. If you try to increment a field by 10 by reading the value, adding 10 then saving without locking, another thread can read the original at the same time , decrement, delay and overwrite your value

@MalikRizwan List.Add isn't thread-safe for the same reason. A List is actually a T[] array with a field pointing to the last valid position. If two threads call Add at the same time, they may read the same original value, increment it at the same time, and thus end up overwriting each other's value. A dictionary is ever more complex. Items are stored internally in buckets of items whose keys have the same hash code. Comparing hash codes is a lot cheaper than comparing the entire key.

@MalikRizwan at this point Dictionary can fail in a similar manner to List - if two threads try to add a key whose hash code hasn't been encountered before, both threads will see there's no bucket and create a new one. Dictionary usually detects this and throws, as canton7 explained. The checks can fail and they don't fix the actual bug in the code - unsafe modification of the Dictionary

@MalikRizwan have you actually tried any of the recommendations until now?


Can a Dictionary have duplicate keys?

No. A Dictionary<K,V> instance can never contain two entries with the same key, unless it is used incorrectly. Some examples of incorrect usage:

Adding keys to the dictionary from two different threads concurrently without synchronization. This is not a supported usage for a Dictionary<K,V>, and results in undefined behavior. For details see the Thread Safety section in the documentation of the type.
Providing the dictionary with a comparer having a flawed IEqualityComparer<T>.Equals implementation. If this method returns false for two keys that are equal, the dictionary will not behave correctly.
Providing the dictionary with a comparer having a flawed IEqualityComparer<T>.GetHashCode implementation. The rule for this method is that equal keys should have equal hashcodes. If you provide the dictionary with a comparer that violates this rule, the behavior of the collection becomes unpredictable.


You must have some special characters that arent visible in one of your keys.
Its not possible to have a duplicate entrys in a .NET standard Dictionary.
You can compare keys using:
var isEqual = String.Equals(key1, key2);


So far, based on the above discussion, this is a failed assumption.

@shingo i replied before 5 edits that has been made on that question when there was nothing about multithreading. A statement is still valid, and there are so many other issues when you build an multithreaded app, that you just cant guess if you dont have that info in the question. Feel free to add your own answer if you are sure about it and if you think it will help the community, if someone runs into similar issue.

I don't think "You must have some special characters that arent visible in one of your key" is still a valid statement. Questioning in the comments (which is what should happen) demonstrated that this is not a problem with special characters. The very first version of the question had a screenshot at the bottom which showed that the first and last keys were equal, when compared using first.Equals(second)
